# Giving credentials for a url in cron job

Tags: linux, cron

I need to write a cron job which hits a url once every day. Problem is that this url needs authentication. How can I authenticate and hit the url through a cron job?

Thanks

Comment: which http client are you using?

Comment: Is this "HTTP authenication" or a regular login? If it's HTTP auth then use wget --http-user=foo --http-passwd=bar http://example.com/page.html

Comment: Hi Adam, Its just a regular login of drupal(PHP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then write a script, example from wget manual

```
# Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
--post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
http://server.com/auth.php

# Now grab the page or pages we care about.
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
-p http://server.com/interesting/article.php
```

then call this script from user cron or system cron.

Comment: Thanks Jasonw, I am getting an error "http request sent awaiting response 403 forbidden" I have also tried it by using firefox but still not resolved. I have used it like "wget -U firefox -r -np --save-cookies cookies.txt \
--post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
http://server.com/auth.php"

Comment: field user and password has to match the login form fields in the server. Is that user agent valid? Please get a valid user agent. why do you want -r and -np during login? You also have to make sure that the request submitted to the right path. I would assume the form action url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a helpful answer, you need to answer Adam's question: "*Is this 'HTTP authenication' or a regular login?*" (though I don't know what he means by "regular login").

Jasonw's answer is *extremely* unlikely to work.

Adam's answer of `wget --http-user=foo --http-passwd=bar http://...` is your best bet.  In fact, given the "403" return code, I am willing to bet that it *is* the answer you need.

Comment: OP question are three statements with no code involve. To me, it sounds that OP want a general idea on how to solve this problem collectively. That was what I'm answering. Now I would prefer if OP can elaborate his question and read into wget manual for various authentication methods than giving specific command on how to do it.